# Bold text in Android Studio.. just one word? java

Tags: java, android, text, android-studio, spinner

I have a spinner in which i need to make one word of it in Bold to make it more readable. Has anybody any idea on how to do this? Iv tried and failed as i seem to only be able to make the whole thing bold.I want to make the word Uses bold.

Heres my code:

```
public class Interactions extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {


Spinner spinner;
TextView showmed;
private String[] state = {"Adalimumab",
        "Etanercept",
        "Tacrolimus",
        "Mycophenolic Acid",
        "Bicalutamide",
        "Darbepoetin alfa",
        "Ciclosporin",
        "Interferon beta-1a",
        "Triptorelin",
        "Pegfilgrastim"
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    if (MinderActivity.alarms) {
        setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
    } else {
        setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_interactions);
    System.out.println(state.length);
    showmed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showmed);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, state);
    adapter_state
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter_state);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                           long id) {

    switch(position)
    {

        case 0:
            showmed.setText("Adalimumab\n" +
                            "Uses:\n" + "Treating a variety of moderate to severe inflammatory conditions (eg, rheumatoid arthritis, juvenile idiopathic arthritis [JIA], psoriatic arthritis, ankylosing spondylitis). It is also used to treat certain patients with moderate to severe Crohn disease, ulcerative colitis, or chronic plaque psoriasis. It may be used alone or in combination with other medicine. It may also be used for other conditions as determined by your doctor.\n" +
                            "\n" + "Alternative Names\n"+ "Humira\n"+ "Risks:\n"+ "Patients who use adalimumab have an increased risk of developing serious and sometimes fatal infections (eg, bacterial, viral, or fungal infections; tuberculosis [TB]). Most patients who developed these infections were also taking medicine that suppressed their immune system (eg, corticosteroids, methotrexate).\"TB may be caused by a new infection or by reactivation of a previous infection. Patients should receive a TB skin test before using adalimumab. Patients who test positive for TB should begin treatment for TB before starting adalimumab. All patients should also be monitored for signs of TB while using adalimumab, even if their TB test is negative.\n" +
                            "\n" + "Interactions\n"+ "\n"


            );
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SpannableStringBuilder` to apply a `new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)` to the portion of text that you want.

Or, wrap that portion in a `<b>` tag and use `Html.fromHtml()`, to have it build the `Spanned` for you with the bold formatting.